# Generate a set of HTML list items from a comma separated list? PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv

I have a field in my database with the text value:

**"these, are, some, keywords"** (minus the inverted commas)

Now, I wonder if I can generate an unordered list from this so ultimately my HTML reads:

```
<ul>
<li>these</li>
<li>are</li>
<li>some</li>
<li>keywords</li>
</ul>
```

Is this possible with PHP and if so is anyone able to help me out with this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with something like the following:

```
<?php
$yourList = "these, are, some, keywords";
$words = explode(',', $yourList);
if(!empty($words)){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($words as $word){
        echo '<li>'.htmlspecialchars($word).'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

As mentioned by elcodedocle, you may want to use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/str_getcsv) instead of explode if more appropriate.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. With a little adjustment. Thank you so much for taking the time to help :-) Green tick incoming....

Comment: +1 for remembering to add `if(!empty($words))` and `htmlspecialchars($word)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$mystring = "these, are,some , keywords";
$myvalues = str_getcsv($mystring);
$myoutput = "<ul>";
foreach ($myvalues as $value){
    $myoutput .= "<li>".trim($value)."</li>\n";
}
$myoutput .= "</ul>";
echo $myoutput;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) you string for `', '`
2. print `<ul>`
3. for each element in the array you received you print `'<li>' . $value . '</li>'`
4. print `</ul>`

Comment: Great! I'll give that a try just now. Are you OK to stay on the line in case I get a bit lost? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$arr = explode(",","these, are, some, keywords");
$res = "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $val){
    $res .=  "<li>" . $val . "</li>";
}
$res .= "</ul>";
echo $res;
```