# How can I generate a set of HTML list items from \n newline separated string using php?

Tags: php, html, delimiter, explode, implode

How can I generate a set of HTML list items from \n newline separated string using php?

I'm using the Google Sheet PHP API with a foreach loop

```
// authentication not shown
$range = 'Sheet3!AD2:Z';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

foreach($values as $val) {
$valuespan = "<span class=\"record\">".implode($val)."</span>";
echo $valuespan;
}
```

to get the HTML output of all rows in the Google Sheet wrapped in span markup like this:
(the \n newlines are shown for illustration)

```
<span class="record">Customer 1 \n
Exercise Physiologist \n
PT, DPT, COMT \n
Class Name \n
South Physical Therapy \n
City 1 \n
AR \n
</span>


<span class="record">Customer 2 \n
Exercise Physiologist \n
PT \n
Class Name \n
Central Therapy \n
City 2 \n
AL \n
</span>
```

...on and on to the last row of the Sheet.

I need to be able to use the \n delimiter to add markup, as I can't use a comma, due to commas being in the data; and I can't add any other delimiters to the Sheet.

So what I need is this specific markup; I need each Customer in `<h1>` tags and the other items in `<li></li>` tags, like this:

```
<span class="record">
<h1>Customer 1</h1>
<ul>
<li>Exercise Physiologist</li>
<li>PT, DPT, COMT</li>
<li>Class Name</li>
<li>South Physical Therapy</li>
<li>City 1</li>
<li>AR</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

I also need to account for empty items, i.e. if the "Class Name" doesn't exits, skip outputting the `<li></li>` for that item.

I've looked at this question [Generate a set of HTML list items from a comma separated list? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202700/generate-a-set-of-html-list-items-from-a-comma-separated-list-php)  but I get the error
`explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given.`

How can I explode/implode to output the needed html?

Or is there another php function more useful?

---

**Edit 12/13/21**

I found I needed to be able to use `if` constructs for some fields, and that didn't work with concatenating the string, so this is what I'm using. It may be ugly in a programmatical sense; if so, add comments.

```
foreach($values as $val) {
$valuearray =explode("\n", implode($val)); // explode string into array
    
$name = $valuearray[0];
$focus = $valuearray[1];
$certification = $valuearray[2];
$course = $valuearray[3];
$business = $valuearray[4];
$url = $valuearray[5];
$address = $valuearray[6];
$city = $valuearray[7];
$state = $valuearray[8];

echo '<h1 class="name">' . $name . '</h1>';
echo '<ul>';

if($focus ?? true) {echo '<li class="focus">Focus: ' . $focus . '</li>'; }

if($certification ?? true) {echo '<li class="certification">Certification: ' . $certification . '</li>'; }

if($course ?? true) {echo '<li class="course">Course: ' . $course . '</li>'; }

if($url ?? true) {
echo '<li class="business">Business: <a class="business-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://' . $url . ' ">' . $business . '</a></li>';
} elseif ($business ?? true) {
echo '<li class="business">Business: ' . $business . '</li>';
}

if($address ?? true) {
echo '<li class="address">Location: ' . $address . ', ' . $city . ', ' . $state . '</li>';
} else {
echo '<li class="address">Location: ' . $city . ', ' . $state . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: What does a sample value for `$val` look like? Does each cell contain the `\n` delimiter?

Comment: Is the data format set in stone? Or can we make suggestions about improvements?

Comment: Hi George, Each record data is all in one Sheet cell, i.e. `Customer 1\nExercise Physiologist\nPT, DPT, COMT\nClass Name\nSouth Physical Therapy\nCity 1\nAR\n`.

Comment: Thanks, BlueDogRanch. I just posted an answer but I will update it with this information.

Comment: Torbjörn, I can't unfortunately change the data format.

Comment: BlueDogRanch, I updated my answer to include headings and to process entries following your example. Please let me know if this addresses your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your cell values use `\n` as a delimiter, first use the [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to explode the cell value from a string to an array. Then, take the first item of this array to add as the header.

The first parameter of the [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function can be used for a separator. You can pass all but the first entry of your array into this function using the [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function. If you want your array items to display as an unordered list, you can use `"</li><li>"` as your separator. To skip empty list items you can use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all instances of `"<li></li>"`.

```php
foreach($values as $val) {
    $valuearray = explode("\n", implode($val)); // explode string into array
    $valuespan = "<span class=\"record\">";
    $valuespan = $valuespan . "<h1>" . $valuearray[0] . "</h1>"; // add heading
    $valuespan = $valuespan . "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", array_slice($valuearray, 1)) . "</li></ul></span>"; // add remaining array as list items
    $valuespan = str_replace("<li></li>", "", $valuespan); // remove empty list items
    echo $valuespan;
}
```

Comment: What about the <h1>?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, Torbjörn. I am updating my answer with new information from the asker.

Comment: Thanks George, but I get the error explode(): Argument #2 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: That means your value `Customer 1\nExercise Physiologist\nPT, DPT, COMT\nClass Name\nSouth Physical Therapy\nCity 1\nAR\n` is being passed as an array. Can you try `explode("\n", implode($val))` and let me know if that works? If it does I will update my answer.

Comment: Cool, that works! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I'm just learning PHP.